# How do I avoid repeating similar code in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code in this code i am using id's which is working fine but its not dynamic.
it should be like one active at a time.

i am repeating the code which is not the right way and i have to use different id where as it should be common classes and simple code

```js
$('#img2').on('click',function(){

$("#2").addClass('text-color');
});

$('#img3').on('click',function(){

$("#3").css("color","white");
});

$('#img4').on('click',function(){

$("#4").css("color","white");
});

$('#img5').on('click',function(){

$("#5").css("color","white");
});

$('#img6').on('click',function(){

$("#6").css("color","white");
});
```

it should be `paralx-dot-1` insted of `#img2`
and it should be `icon-text` insted of `#2`

only one #2/icon-text change its color at a time and other icon-color remain the same

```html
 <ul class="paralx-position">
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="2">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="3">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text-main">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></img></span></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="4">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="5">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="6">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></img></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [Regex selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: if I click first `paralx-dots` this color might be white except this everything is may be black color?

Comment: if you click paralx-dot-1 its respective text span will change its color to white everything is happening on image

Comment: @InderjeetVyas check the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/mp58hd4o/)

Simplest I can understand you want to add class to previous span sibling on the image tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[id^=img]').click(function(){
            var prevSpan = $(this).prev('span');
            prevSpan.css("color","white");
            alert(prevSpan.text()); // for debugging
    });
});
```

where selector `$('img[id^=img]')` selects all controls `img` tags having Id starts with string `"img"`

And `$(this).prev('span')` searches for sibling `span` that placed previous of the `img` tag

**EDIT:** Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/mp58hd4o/6/)

Add a class `.highlight`

```
.highlight {
  color: white;
}
```

then use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[id^=img]').click(function(){
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        var prevSpan = $(this).prev('span');
        prevSpan.addClass("highlight");
        alert(prevSpan.text()); // for debugging    
    });
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: your code is doing exactly the same thanks a lot for shorten the code but the thing i want ( https://unsee.cc/b4f0fb23/ ) if you look at the pic you can see both Accelerate and Transform are getting white color where as it should be only selected image (dot) text should be white

Comment: It worked thank-you very very much @Mayank god bless you.

Comment: heyy @Mayank can you please elaborate this $('img[id^=img]')  why you used ^ this Bitwise exclusive OR operator ! its quite astonishing

Comment: @InderjeetVyas Similar to regular expression, `^=` means 'begins with' followed by the pattern 'img' like in ( img1, img2 ... ) for the selector ids. You can search for wildcard selectors in Jquery for such selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this far more efficient by using a generic query selector and avoiding hardcoded IDs - this also makes the code far more readable and maintainable. One sample way of doing this for your DOM structure would be:

```js
// Query for all li elements inside the ul with hthe class paralx-position
var $lis = $('ul.paralx-position > li');
// Query for all img tags which is a direct child of a li element 
$lis.find(' > img').click(function(){

  // Reset all span colors
  $lis.find('> span').css('color','black')
  
  // Set the color of span which is a sibling of the clicked image
  $(this).parent().find('> span').css('color','blue')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paralx-position">
  <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="2">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img>
  </li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="3">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></img>
  </li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text-main">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1" id="img1" tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></img></span></img>
  </li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="4">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4" tabindex="0"></img>
  </li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="5">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></img>
  </li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="6">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></img>
  </li>
</ul>
```